# UnsatisfiedDependencyException error in creating bean name in REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**
2021-11-26 20:30:57.375  WARN 11700 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2021-11-26 20:30:57.376  INFO 11700 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-26 20:30:57.382  INFO 11700 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-26 20:30:57.393  INFO 11700 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-11-26 20:30:57.396  INFO 11700 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-11-26 20:30:57.410  INFO 11700 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-26 20:30:57.437 ERROR 11700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:
**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

bookRestController (field private BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.BookService BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.Rest.BookRestController.bookService)
┌─────┐
|  bookServiceImpl (field private BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.BookService BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.serviceImpl.BookServiceImpl.bookService)
└─────┘

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.*

**BasicProjectApplication.java**

````
```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}```

**AuthorDAO.java**
```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.dao;

import java.util.List;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;

public interface AuthorDAO {
    public Author findById(int id);
    public List<Book> findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor();
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public void save(Author author);
}```

**BookDAO.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.dao;

import java.util.List;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;

public interface BookDAO {
    public Book findById(int id);
    public List<Author> findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook();
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public void save(Book book);
}```

**AuthorDAOImpl.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.daoImpl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.dao.AuthorDAO;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
@Repository
public class AuthorDAOImpl implements AuthorDAO {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Author findById(int id) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Author author = session.get(Author.class, id);
        
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor() {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<Book> theQuery = session.createQuery("from Book",Book.class);
        
        List<Book> book = theQuery.getResultList();
        return book;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        Query theQuery = session.createQuery("delete from Author where author_id=:theid");
        theQuery.setParameter("theid", id);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Author author) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.saveOrUpdate(author);
    }

}```
**BookDAOImpl.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.daoImpl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.dao.BookDAO;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
@Repository
public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO {
    
    @Autowired
    private  EntityManager  entityManager;

    @Override
    public Book findById(int id) {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Book b = session.get(Book.class, id);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Author> findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook() {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<Author> q = session.createQuery("from Author",Author.class);
        List<Author> author = q.getResultList();
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query q = session.createQuery("delete from Book where book_id:=theid");
        q.setParameter("theid", id);
        q.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Book book) {
        
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.saveOrUpdate(book);
        
    }

}```

**Address.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
    String country;
    public Address(String street, String city, String country) {
        super();
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }
    public Address() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
}```
**Author.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    String authorName;
    Address address;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Book> book;
    public Author() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Author(int id, String authorName,Address address,List<Book> book) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.authorName = authorName;
        this.address = address;
        this.book = book;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }
    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public List<Book> getBook() {
        return book;
    }
    public void setBook(List<Book> book) {
        this.book = book;
    }
    
}```
**Book.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    String book_name;
    String subject;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Author> author;
    public Book() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Book(int id, String book_name, String subject, List<Author> author) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.book_name = book_name;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.author = author;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getBook_name() {
        return book_name;
    }
    public void setBook_name(String book_name) {
        this.book_name = book_name;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public List<Author> getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(List<Author> author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    
    
}```

**AuthorRestController**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.Rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.AuthorService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class AuthorRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthorService authorService;
    

    @GetMapping("/author/{id}")
    public Author getAuthorById(@PathVariable int id )
    {
        return authorService.findById(id);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/book")
    public List<Book> getBook()
    {
        return authorService.findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveAuthor")
    public void setAuthor(@RequestBody Author author)
    {
        authorService.save(author);
    }
    
    
}```

**BookRestController.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.Rest;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.BookService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class BookRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/book/{id}")
    public Book getBookById(@PathVariable int id )
    {
        return bookService.findById(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/author")
    public List<Author> getAuthor()
    {
        return bookService.findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook();
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/saveBook")
    public void setBook(@RequestBody Book book)
    {       
        bookService.save(book);
    }
    
}```

**AuthorService.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service;

import java.util.List;


import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;

public interface AuthorService {
    public Author findById(int id);
    public List<Book> findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor();
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public void save(Author author);
}```

**BookService.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service;

import java.util.List;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
public interface BookService {

    public Book findById(int id);
    public List<Author> findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook();
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public void save(Book book);
    
}```

**AuthorServiceImpl.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.serviceImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.dao.AuthorDAO;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.AuthorService;
@Service
public class AuthorServiceImpl implements AuthorService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorDAO authorDAO;
    
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Author findById(int id) {
        return authorDAO.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Book> findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor() {
        return authorDAO.findListOfBookWrittenByAuthor();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        authorDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Author author) {
        authorDAO.save(author);
    }

}```

**BookServiceImpl.java**

```package BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.serviceImpl;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Author;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.entity.Book;
import BookAuthorManyToManyRelationship.service.BookService;
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;
    

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Book findById(int id) {
        return bookService.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Author> findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook() {
        return bookService.findListOfAuthorWhoHasWrittenThisBook();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        bookService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Book book) {
        bookService.save(book);
    }
    
}
```
````

Comment: Seems it has a circular dependency, it is not a best practice to have the design like this. Try to mitigate the circular barrier.

Comment: First decide what you want to use `hibernate` or `Spring-data-jpa` both crud operation are different. you mixing `spring data jpa` and `hibernate`

Comment: please, read it carefully: https://stackabuse.com/build-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-java-full-guide/

Answer (score 0):

here is cause of your problem

```
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    
@Autowired
private BookService bookService
```

I am not able to understand why do you have reference of `BookService` inside it's own implementation, my best guess you wanted to add `BookDAO` here.